# How to write double value into JTextField?

Tags: java, swing, double, jtextfield

I want to input a price and write it into a text file, but it gives a "double cannot be dereferenced" error.

This is a snippet of my code.

```
String id = "P" + ProductID.getText();
String name = ProductName.getText();
String brand = ProductBrand.getText();
String model = ProductModel.getText();
String type = ProductType.getText();
double price = Double.parseDouble(ProductPrice.getText());

if (id.isEmpty() || name.isEmpty() || brand.isEmpty() || model.isEmpty() || type.isEmpty() || price.isEmpty())
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please Fill In Everything!", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}
```

Comment: Best practice would be to put a try catch block around where you call parseDouble. If you get a ParseException here, you can / should show a message to the user saying that they haven't entered a valid number in this field

Answer (score 2):

`price` is a primitive type of `double` - it is not an object. So you cannot perform an operation like `.xxx()` on it.

Instead you can check for example

```
if(price != 0.0)
```

Comment: Good answer, but you shouldn't use equals operators on doubles. Math is weird.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
String tmp = ProductPrice.getText();
if(tmp.isEmpty()) // error
else{
double price = Double.parseDouble(tmp);
// do something
}
```